# Dividing in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

There is a possibility to divide complex numbers below?

$$ \frac{z}{z-i} $$

Comment: Hint : Multiply numerator and denominator by $z+i$. What do you get ?

Comment: Even better, use $\bar z+i$

Comment: @Peter $\frac{z^2+iz}{z^2+1}$

Comment: @SimonWieniawski Only in the case $z=-i$, the expressions are not equivalent, but this case can easily be handled.

Comment: @Andrei $\frac{|z|^2+i\overline{z}}{|z|^2+i(2\Re(z))+1}$. Basicaly I want to expand it into a series, so in numerator I need somehow got real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{z}{z-i}=\frac{z(\bar z+i)}{(z-i)(\bar z+i)}=\frac{|z|^2+iz}{|z|^2+1+i(z-\bar z)}$$
Now $z=\Re z+i\Im z$, $\bar z=\Re z-i\Im z$, so $z-\bar z=2i\Im z$. Therefore:
$$ \frac{z}{z-i}=\frac{|z|^2+iz}{|z|^2+1-2\Im z}$$
The denominator is a real number